# Deleting the back element in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

This is not a duplicate of the question with a similar name, This involves OOP and new and delete calls.

I'm trying to write a function that will iterate to the back of my linked list and then delete the allocated memory in the heap of the last node.

Here is my code:

```
void LinkedList::delete_back(){
    if(head != NULL){
            ListNode *end = head;
            while(end->next != NULL)
                    end = end->next;
            delete end;
    }
    size--;
}
```

And here is my class definitions:

```
class ListNode{

    public:
            Item data;
            ListNode *next;
};
class LinkedList{

    private:
            ListNode *head;
            int size;

    public:
            LinkedList();
            ~LinkedList(); 
            bool empty();
            void insert_front(Item i);
            void insert_back(Item i);
            void delete_front();
            void delete_back();
            void print();
};
```

Annddddd.....this is the problem, I get spammed with error messages like this from valgrind, some stating invalid read of size 4, other stating invalid read of size 8:

```
==4385== Invalid read of size 4
==4385==    at 0x400CAA: LinkedList::print() (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==4385==    by 0x400EDD: main (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==4385==  Address 0x5a04f30 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==4385==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4385==    by 0x400C5E: LinkedList::delete_back() (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==4385==    by 0x400E99: main (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
```

I'll post the rest of the errors if that helps but I don't feel like hitting space 4 times on 50 lines unless I need to.  Does anyone know what this could be? What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE-----------------------
I've edited the code to be:

```
void LinkedList::delete_back(){
    if(head != NULL){
            ListNode *end = head;
            ListNode *prev_end;
            while(end->next != NULL){
                    prev_end = end;
                    end = end->next;
            }
            prev_end->next = NULL;
            if(end != NULL) delete end;
            size--;
    }
}
```

I'm now getting more invalid read of size 8/4 errors and invalid free/delete errors

```
==5294== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==5294==    at 0x4C2A4BC: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
```

and this:

```
==5294== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==5294==    at 0x400C3D: LinkedList::delete_back() (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
==5294==    by 0x400EEC: main (in /home/jon/jball2_lab06/linkedlist)
```

Here is the test code im using:

```
    for(Item i = 50; i < 100; i++){
            ll.insert_back(i);
            cout << "Inserted [" << i << "] in back.\n";
    }
    ll.print();
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            ll.delete_back();
    cout << "Removed 50 elements from the back.\n";
    ll.print();
```

This occurs when the last element is removed from the list using delete_back()

UPDATE-------------------------

The problem was that if end->next is null than the while loop will never execute, prev_end will never be initalized.  Posted answer with fixes implemented.

Comment: Kind of off topic but..... you can copy and paste them four spaces instead of entering them seperately ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a list that contains at least 2 nodes and you `delete` the last one. The previous one still has a reference to the last one (which doesn't exist anymore), which results in *undefined behavior* by the time your `print` tries to dereference invalid (dangling) pointer. Instead of:

```
ListNode *end = head;
while(end->next != NULL)
    end = end->next;
delete end;
```

you should do:

```
if (head->next == NULL) {
    delete head;
    head = NULL;
}
else {
    ListNode *nextToEnd = head;
    ListNode *end = head->next;
    while (end->next != NULL) {
        nextToEnd = end;
        end = end->next;
    }
    delete end;
    nextToEnd->next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Ah so create another temp pointer to keep track of the node before the last that way I can set it equal to null.  So you're saying the invalid read errors are coming from having pointers that point to nothing?

Comment: @Riptyde4: Yes. Try to apply this change and see whether valgrind still complains.

Comment: Looks like I was actually wrong, edited the question, I've still got a problem somewhere

Comment: On line three of the second block, how is it possible to set head to the value of NULL if it is already deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to update `next` of your new last element.

```
void LinkedList::delete_back(){
    if(head != NULL){
            ListNode *end = head;
            ListNode *prev_end;
            while(end->next != NULL)
            {
                 prev_end = end;
                 end = end->next;
            }
            prev_end->next = 0;
            delete end;
    }
```

Also if you emptied the list, set head to NULL.

Comment: I actually used this code instead of the top one since it was closer to the way I already had it coded. Thanks!

Comment: How could i go about checking if the list is empty other than checking if head is null? Also, i edited my question...seems to more more problems

Answer (score 1):

you are not setting the new end node to be null.

For eg:

> A->B->C->NULL

When you delete C , B's next is a dangling pointer

So in the delete function you need to go to the second last node and and set its next to NULL.

In the above example after deleting C , the list should look like

> A->B->NULL instead of A->B->(dangling)

So you can delete B in the next delete_back operation.

You can do something like below

```
void LinkedList::delete_back(){
if(head != NULL){
        ListNode *end = head;
        //This if block is for when only one element is left
        if(end->next == NULL)
         { delete end;
           end = NULL;
         }
        else
        while(end!= NULL)
        { 
               if(end->next) /// reach the second last element
                if(end->next->next==NULL)
                 {
                  delete end->next; //delete the last element
                  end->next=NULL; // set the next of second last element to NULL
                 }
               end=end->next;
        } 
  size--;
  }
  }
```

Comment: oops i did not see the previous two answers

Answer (score 0):

Fixed all issues.

Code:

```
void LinkedList::delete_back(){
    if(head != NULL){
            ListNode *end = head;
            if(end->next != NULL){
                    ListNode *prev_end;
                    while(end->next != NULL){
                            prev_end = end;
                            end = end->next;
                    }
                    prev_end->next = NULL;
                    delete end;
            }
            else {
                    delete head;
                    head = NULL;
            }
            size--;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the same code I posted yesterday with the only difference: you decrement `size` at the end...

Comment: Yeah basically, I left out the else clause and it was causing an error. stupid mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

like this should work

```
void del_rear()

{
  struct node *end, *last

 if (head->next != NULL) {

   *end=head;

while(end->next!=null){
*last=end;
 end=end->next;
  }
    free(end);
    last->next=null;
   }     
 else
   {

    pf("list is empty\n");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest code to delete at end is:

```
void DeleteAtLast(){
    node *temp=head;
    while(temp->next->next!=NULL){
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp-next=NULL;
}
```

Comment: Avoid code-only answers. Please edit your answer to include explanations of your code. You can read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303598/low-quality-but-still-an-answer/303605#303605) about code-only answers.